# Authorization design guidance for Azure Mobile Apps / Web API for a company-exclusive user base

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I've searched for some definitive and COMPLETE guidance on how to the following scenario, but have not been very successful.

My requirement is, I would guess, a pretty common one.  Company users accessing services on Azure via a Windows 10 app.  It looks like this: [Windows 10 mobile device] <-> [Azure Mobile Apps] <-> [On-Premise Company Data].  Only company users (those who have accounts on our on-premise AD) are allowed to access the Azure services.

I've done the following steps:

1. Create an Azure Mobile App service using my MSDN subscription (using my Micrsoft Account).
2. Created a Windows 10 app that syncs with the Azure Mobile App service.
3. Implemented **authentication** (not authorization) using Microsoft Accounts

Questions:
1.  In production, I obviously should not use the Azure subscription from my MSDN subscription.   How do I create the azure account for my company?
2. How do I implement authorization?   With the MS account authentication I've implemented so far, the user identity is verified, but how do I restrict who can access the service, and what they can access?  Seen lots of examples, but none using MS Accounts.  Is this possible with MS accounts?  Or do I have to use Azure AD?
3. If I should be using AAD, how do I link AAD and our on-premise AD such that users have the same user id/password when accessing on-premise resources and azure mobile app resources?
4. If using AAD, can I set attributes for users that I can inspect in my azure web API controllers to implement authorization

Thanks

Comment: This is actually 3 different questions. For question #1, someone who is an admin on your company Azure account needs to create the App Service. #2 and #4 can be posted as one question. #3 is a different question and should be tagged azure-active-directory. Please edit your question to include only #2 and #4, and post #3 as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My blog is currently covering authentication / authorization with groups and AAD.  You can find it here: https://shellmonger.com/  It covers the requirements within Azure Mobile Apps hopefully comprehensively.

Comment: I wish I discovered your blog months ago.   It would have saved me many, many hours.   Thanks for writing the blog.